# Trial Completion time is not right skewed but it should be

Tags: normal-distribution, t-test, data-transformation, skewness

Main Question:
I am wondering why my completion time data for trials is not as skewed as the completion time for the tasks that makeup the trial?

Details:
I am comparing two user interfaces on task completion time. The participants were given a set of tasks to complete with UI-A and the same set of tasks to complete with UI-B. For each interface participants completed the tasks twice. The order in which the tasks appeared was randomized and counterbalanced. I have noticed that if I look at the completion time for each task within the trials I get a right skewed plot (as expected with RT).

[image: Histogram of completion times for the individual tasks withing the trial]
         **Histogram of completion times for the individual tasks withing the trial**

However, if I summarize the data i.e., look at the time to complete all the tasks in a trial then I get something more normal looking. The point of looking at trial completion time is to determine overall which interface is more efficient.

[image: Histogram of Trial Completion Time]
           **Histogram of Trial Completion Time**

I had expected a right skewed plot since the task times within a trial are right skewed. Now I am wondering why the data is not as skewed? Doing some research on response time I came across a paper titled Effective Analysis of Reaction Time Data. Based on this article it appears that the tasks within the trial can be seen as raw response time and the summarized trial data could be looked at as aggregating the data. However, this does not sit right with me since I only summarized the task completion times to get total trial times.

Also, based on the aforementioned article one approach to normalizing response time data is to perform a log transformation on the completion times to reduce, but it is not clear to me if I should perform the log calculations on the individual task times or on the summarized trial times? Based on the trial completion time plot it may not even be necessary to do any transformations since T-Test is fairly robust against data that is not exactly normal

Comment: If you can get it without too much effort, what's the third moment skewness of the sample of total values and of both of the components of that total?

Comment: Not sure which sample of values you were referring to but here it is for the data for Completion times for the individual tasks within a single trial. Using the following R command "moment(x, order=3, center=TRUE)" I get 1.164853e+14. Similarly for the Trial Completion Time (summed values - second graph) I get 7.4913e+15

Comment: Those are unscaled moments which will be tricky to interpret -- what are the corresponding standard deviations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second histogram is *clearly* right skew. It's just not as right skew as the components you started with.

This is exactly what you should expect.

The distributions of sums of random variables will tend to be less skew than the variables that make up the sum.

For example, consider samples from two and four identical distributions shaped like the first histogram, and the distribution of their sums:

[image: histograms of exponential(1) and of sums of two and four exponential variates]

This is fairly typical of the kind of thing you see, though if one component of the sum is much more variable than the others it will tend to "dominate" the shape; nevertheless the sum will still tend to be less skew than the most skew component. When you add an independent random component to another, you get a convolution of their densities, which results a kind of "smearing out" or blurring - peaks become rounder, shapes become more symmetric.

If you add a *lot* of terms, you (slowly) tend to get closer to normally-distributed totals.

If we assume independence of the component times and look at the skewness measure based on third moments we can even quantify how much this tends to happen.

Specifically if we consider [cumulants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulant) (which are related to moments) we can use the fact that the cumulants of independent random variables "add" (the $k$th cumulant of the sum is the sum of $k$th cumulants).

[The first cumulant is the mean, the second cumulant is the variance, and the third cumulant is the third central moment; the fourth cumulant is not the fourth central moment, but we'll just use the first three for now]

If you have variables drawn independently from two distributions, the first with mean $\mu_1$, variance $\sigma^2_1$ and third central moment $\theta_1$, and the second with corresponding values $\mu_2$, $\sigma^2_2$ and $\theta_2$, then the mean, variance and third central moment of the sum will be$\mu_1+\mu_2$, $\sigma^2_1+\sigma^2_2$ and $\theta_1+\theta_2$ respectively.

The skewness coefficients of the components will be $\theta_1/\sigma_1^3$ and $\theta_2/\sigma_2^3$ and the skewness of the sum of components will be $\frac{\theta_1+\theta_2}{(\sigma_1^2+\sigma_2^2)^{3/2}}$.

Imagine for simplicity that the standard deviations of both distributions is about the same. Then the third-moment-skewness of the sum would be about 70% of the *average* of those two skewness values. If you added 100 of them (again assuming about equal standard deviations) the skewness would reduce to about 10% of the average skewness.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for to help understand my data. However, it leads to another question. If am checking for normality do I do it based on the individual task completion times or the summed trial completion times. Although the summed trial completion times is right skewed I would think that the T-Test was robust enough to manage. However, if normality is based on the individual task time then a transformation is needed. Furthermore, if doing a transformation do I transform the individual task times or the total task time. I think I read you would transform the individual times.

Comment: 1. Clearly if you add two (independent) right skewed things the result will be right skewed; you know you don't have normality (in particular, a test of normality is pointless here). If you're just considering how much effect a little skewness might have on something, it's best to consider that issue directly - but do it with what you want to run the t-test on. 2. You say: "*I would think that the T-Test was robust enough to manage*" -- in large samples, the significance level may be reasonable (the t-test does have reasonable "level-robustness") if the tail is not very heavy, ... ctd

Comment: ctd... but you can still have more serious issues with power.  3. If you're considering transformation, you transform the thing you want to use the test on -- but transformation wouldn't be the first thing I'd consider -- I'd start by looking at models better suited to data that are times -- most likely Gamma GLMs would be my first thought. One advantage there is you don't need to have any tension between the fact that the component times add and what distributional model you use, because sums of gammas are also gamma. See the three plots at the top of my post? All gamma distributions.

Comment: Thanks for the information Glen_b. Your comment "but do it with what you want to run the t-test on." is what I was thinking and thus would transform the total times since I am interested in overall efficiency. Some of the reading I had been doing appeared to say that the transformation should happen on the raw data.  However, I should not that I decides to use on nonparametric test instead of transforming the data. I can be more challenging to explain log values to upper management and others than the median.

Comment: 1. Note that if you transform times to say log-times, the sum of the logs *is not the log of the sum* so you can't just add the components if you take logs. 2. If you use GLM there's no transformation involved, your model is for the mean time. 3. Which nonparametric test do you think is about medians?? (There's a lot of completely wrong information about many nonparametric tests, including in a lot of the basic stats books used in psychology. If you're thinking that Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney or signed rank tests are about medians you'd be mistaken.)

Comment: Interesting that you what you say about "signed rank tests are about medians you'd be mistaken". I have been spending the last day trying to understand what exactly is the information provided by the Wicoxon Signed Rank Test. In the past I have unknowingly used the mean and run the appropriate parametric test based on the study design. In this case I thought the Wilcoxon Sign Rank test would be more appropriate instead of a paired t-test due to the data being skewed. Based on what I have researched it appeared that it was a test of the medians.

Comment: I repeat, the signed rank test is not a test of medians; this is easy to demonstrate (e.g. by simply supplying data where the medians are exactly the same but the test rejects). It's also well known what it *is* a test of (the relevant population quantity is the population pseudomedian - the median of averages of random pairs of values from a single population ... in a paired test these are medians of averages of pairs of pair-differences). Unless your sources give the appropriate caveats, if they say it's a test of medians, they're wrong ... ctd

Comment: This is actually, the second part to the above comment. I forgot to hit submit. Matter of fact I have come across a number of articles that stated the Wilcoxon Signed Rank Test should be reported with the Median along with the z score, p value and r value. Which is what I was doing with my data, however I have am not convinced I have a good handle on what the data means when using the Wilcoxon Sign Rank Test. Also when you mention GLM are you referring to general linear models or generalized. I believe you mean generalized since the response variable does not need to be transformed.

Comment: ctd ... Many books - especially books written by non-statisticians - incorrectly make the claim that it's a test of medians (presumably because their authors read only what other books in their application area say instead of spending time understanding what the test actually *does*). Some say "under the assumption of symmetry this implies the equality of medians", which is true, but symmetry is only an assumption *under the null hypothesis* so again, it's not a test of whether the medians differ. ... ctd

Comment: ctd... If you choose to add an assumption under the alternative of a location-shift, then it becomes a test of medians, but also of many other things (even means, if means exist)

Comment: @Doc I meant generalized linear model, sorry for the ambiguity. I forget that certain pieces of software tend to use GLM for general linear model. You're free to state the median of the differences or the difference of the medians or any other thing you like but it's probably going to look funny if you say "median difference: 0" and "test significant at 0.001 level".

Comment: ok that is what I figured. I am going to spend some time on generalized linear models. Specifically the Gamma GLM you mentioned. By any chance do you have any good references?

Comment: For generalized linear models? Probably none that would be useful to you because the ones I have tend to emphasize the theory (and how to do the computations to fit them). Cosma Shalizi's [*Advanced data analysis from an elementary point of view*](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~cshalizi/ADAfaEPoV/ADAfaEPoV.pdf) has a chapter related to GLMs that's good but it's quite brief (still downloadable at his page). Maybe Faraway's book? (*Extending the Linear Model with R: Generalized Linear, Mixed Effects and
Nonparametric Regression Models* -- though my experience of it is brief, it looked okay) ...ctd

Comment: ctd... I gather that John Fox's book *Applied Regression Analysis and Generalized Linear Models* is pretty decent on introducing GLMs but I don't know that he does much on Gamma models, you'd have to check. Oh, for gamma glms Piet de Jong and Gillian Heller's little book (*Generalized Linear Models for Insurance Data*) may be useful in that it has a few specific examples, but it's focused on a particular application area (for that matter Frees' book *Regression modelling with actuarial and financial applications* has some specific applications as well - such as ch17 - but has the same issue).

Comment: If you're looking to do work with repeated measures (and so may move to GLMMs) perhaps Ben Bolker's book would be useful. There's a number of questions on site here on Gamma GLMs that may be useful to you. You can do the equivalent of a two sample test by supplying a factor / dummy variable indicating the two groups. If you want a log link or identity link instead of the default inverse link that's pretty easy to do and for times all are easy to interpret. If you have continuous covariates the choice of link may matter more.